Construct a $C^{1}$ function with a non-$C^{1}$ projection
The problem is stated as follows:
Construct a $C^{1}$ function $G:R^{2}\rightarrow R$ such that $\{(x,y) \in R^2: G(x,y)>0\}=(0,1)\times(0,1)$
Every function that I think of has edges that make the gradient discontinuous. I have no more ideas.
Thank you for the help!

Can you do it in dimension 1?

You mean like $G(x)=x(1-x)$?

Start with
$$ f(x,y) = x^3 (1-x)^3 y^3 (1-y)^3 $$
which is $>0$ in $5$ regions, and change its sign in four of those regions.  Thus
$$ G(x,y) = \cases{- x^3 (1-x)^3 y^3 (1-y)^3 & if $x > 1$ and $y > 1$, or $x > 1$ and $y < 0$, or $x < 0$ and $y > 1$, or $x < 0$ and $y < 0$\cr x^3 (1-x)^3 y^3 (1-y)^3 &  otherwise}$$
